# \rowcolors not working with \multirow

Tags: tables, pdftex

Note: I know there were other people asking the same question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269547/rowcolor-for-a-multirow) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266255/table-with-multirow-and-rowcolors), but none of there examples were *minimal*, and I'm still confuzzled. Sorry for the inconvience.

---

I know I can do this:

```
%rowcolor-multirow-test.tex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{slg}{gray}{0.95}
% ^^ "super-light gray" -- the builtin 'lightgray' isn't light enough.
\begin{document}

Wrong: \\
\rowcolors{1}{white}{slg}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
  A & B & C & D \\
  \multirow{2}{*}{Hello!} & foo & bar & 42 \\
  & fooo & baar & 13 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Right:\\
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
  A & B & C & D \\
  & foo & bar & 42 \\
  \multirow{-2}{*}{Hello!} & fooo & baar & 13 \\
  % ^^ Put it on the odd rows and give it a negative number to span up.
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

To get this:
[image: Obligatory xkcd: http://xkcd.com/1341]

---

But how can I get this, preferably with the vertical lines intact?
[image: What did you expect, something funny?]
(I cheated and colored the cells manually with `\cellcolor[gray]{0.95}`)

*pdfLaTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is by using the `\cellcolor` command inside the cell that you want to have a different color. Note that this is not the cell containing the `\multirow` command but the one above it that you need to place the command in.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\definecolor{slg}{gray}{0.95}
\begin{document}

\rowcolors{1}{white}{slg}

Fixed:\\
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
    A & B & C & D \\
    \cellcolor{white} & foo & bar & 42 \\
    \multirow{-2}{*}{Hello!} & fooo & baar & 13 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What you wrote doesn't seem to match the image you put; I get all rows white. Changing `white` to `lightgray` Doesn't work either.

Comment: The code is meant to work further on your example, i.e. it implies that you use the `\rowcolors{1}{white}{slg}` command. I have updated my answer for clarity

Comment: Ah. Thanks, works perfectly. Could this be made to be a run-once thing?

Comment: What do you mean be a 'run-once thing'?

Comment: i.e., Do `\xyzzy` at the start of the table, does everything else automagically. Or would that be too shenanigans-y?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v 5.8 of 2021-01-01) provides an easy way to do that.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c|c|c|c}
\CodeBefore 
  \rowcolors[gray]{1}{}{0.95}[cols=2-*]
\Body
  A & B & C & D \\
  \Block{2-1}{Hello!} & foo & bar & 42 \\
  & fooo & baar & 13 \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Ouput of the above code]